# How to add new keys and values to dictionaries inside of a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this is a basic question, but how can i add a new key-value pair to my dictionaries inside my list?

I want to loop over the first list so the first list-value goes to the first list dictionary with a key of 'quantity' and so on, see the output below.

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'Tights 1', 'price': Decimal('200.00'), 'category_id': 1}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'Tights 2', 'price': Decimal('400.00'), 'category_id': 1}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'title': 'Tights 1', 'price': Decimal('200.00'), 'quantity': 1, 'category_id': 1}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'Tights 2', 'price': Decimal('400.00'), 'quantity': 2, 'category_id': 1}]
```

Comment: So you want to add a `category_id` key to each dictionary, is that correct? Where is the code which is supposed to do that?

Comment: your item.quantity is an int, how may you loop through it?

Comment: Not quite, the first number (1) goes into the first dictionary(with "id":1) with a key of "quantity". Then number 2 goes into dict "id:": 2, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new key pair value into your dictionary you do:

```
dict['new_key'] = new_value
```

So adapting your code to create a new entry:

```
from decimal import Decimal
order_item_values = [{'id': 1, 'title': 'Tights 1', 'price': Decimal('200.00'), 'category_id': 1}, {'id': 2, 'title': 'Tights 2', 'price': Decimal('400.00'), 'category_id': 1}]


for item in order_item_values:
    item['quantity'] = item['id']
print(order_item_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the list and add the elements to each dictionary.

```
lst = list(item.values())
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i]["quantity"] = i + 1
```

Comment: That did it, thank you. I've not done a lot of python lists yet.